# Response::download not working after transfer site to another server laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

after transfer site to new server

```
public function download($filename)
    {
      $file= base_path(). "/uploads/pagefiles/$filename/".$filename;
        $headers = array(
                  'Content-Type: application/pdf',
                );

        return Response::download($file, "$filename", $headers);
    }
```

new server use PHP5.5
while the oldest one use PHP7
the file download if i put the link directly in browsers

Comment: What kind of error you are getting? (browser and log)

Comment: @AgeValed  Internal Server Error check this link http://www.papermideast.com/m/floor-plan

Comment: I tested the code on PHP 5.6.22 and works, so I think you hay have another kind of error, wrong path, missing PHP library or something else

Comment: old server : http://hyper-design.com/paper/m/floor-plan 
new server : http://www.papermideast.com/m/floor-plan

Comment: can you check the apache error logs?

Comment: no errors stored in this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138748/discussion-between-agevaled-and-mohamed-mehanny).